# New ESP32-D0WD-V3 based board has WiFi issues in transmit; receive is OK

Tags: antenna, impedance, esp32, wifi, matching

I have a custom board with the above chip, and it all works except for the WiFi transmit functionality. I can receive fine with -60 RSSI from my AP 50 meters away, and I receive all my neighbours' signals.

However, it will not connect to my AP, and if I set the device as an AP, I can't see it even with my phone < 1 inch away.

Is there anything that I have to set in the chip to get it to transmit, like an eFuse or something? I have followed all the guides on impedance matching from Expressif and calculators, and am pretty sure I have that right.

I can't see it being a matching issue if I can receive fine but not even transmit even a sniff of a signal. I checked with rhe WiFi Analyser app on my phone.

PS: The Arduino software I used to set the chip in AP mode works fine on a dev board with a similar chip (ESP32-DOWDQ6), I think that is a V1 chip, whereas I am using V3 chip, the only difference.

[image: Top of board]

Comment: I’d be suspecting pcb layout and component choice first.

Comment: Can you be specific, which component choices, the Pi network? Gone
 over that a million times..:)

Comment: There’s only a handful of components. You might want to show your pcb layout.

Comment: Have added picture of layout. C26 is 3.3pF, L1 is 1.8nH, C24 is 3.9pF

Comment: Sorry C26 is 5.3pF

Comment: @Kartman Any thoughts?

Comment: Some of your tracks have significant inductance at the frequency of operation. I’d suggest you copy a Espressif layout. As well, is there supposed to be a ground plane layer on your pcb? Four layer pcb?

Comment: I notice the part that was supplied to the board was a chinese copy, rather than the expressif part ... anyone know of any issues with these versions of the chip .. like Wifi TX not working ... grasping at straws here ...

Comment: The Antenna was designed as per the Cypress document https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91445_Antenna_Design_and_RF_Layout_Guidelines-ApplicationNotes-v09_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073e054f6227&utm_source=cypress&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=202110_globe_en_all_integration-files&redirId=File_1_3_1152 Section 7.4.

Comment: The track feeding the antenna is a co-linear feed line designed using the Kicad tool and is designed for 2.44Ghz and for standard 1.6mm FR4 material. There is ground plane top and bottom, for clarity, I did not show in the picture above, but you can see the via stitching them together. It is two layer board. Can you be specific, what tracks have "significant inductance" and what do you base that statement on? ..

Comment: The PI matching network was calculated from here: https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/impedance-matching

Comment: Your power supply routing for one has skinny tracks and poor capacitor placement. You are pushing your luck with a two layer pcb. Do yourself a favour and use a module - they’re only around $3usd each. Even these are a highly cost engineered product and have a four layer pcb. That should tell you something.